# How to authenticate when connecting to a proxy server inside ubuntu-based docker container?

Tags: networking, proxy, docker, container

I am building a docker container that should use proxy server when sending HTTP requests. Unfortunately I can't get it to work - I can't authenticate to the proxy from inside the container, even though credentials are correct.

Expected result
`curl https://api.myip.com` returns JSON response with proxy's IP

Actual result:
`curl https://api.myip.com` returns `curl: (56) Received HTTP code 407 from proxy after CONNECT`

What I tried:

- setting HTTP_PROXY env variables (same for HTTPS env)
- adding "Acquire::http::Proxy" string to /etc/apt/apt.conf (same for https)
- tried different configurations (only ENV, only apt.conf file, both)

What I checked:

- /etc/apt/apt.conf contains desired lines (provided below)
- ENVs are set correctly inside the container
- proxy is working correctly outside the container
- proxy authentication works correctly (authorization successful) via browser run from outside the container
- docker networking works properly (no problems when not using proxy)

my apt.conf:

```
Acquire::http::Proxy "http://<my_login>:<my_pass>@<proxy_ip>:<proxy_port>/";
Acquire::https::Proxy "https://<my_login>:<my_pass>@<proxy_ip>:<proxy_port>/";
Acquire::socks::Proxy "socks://<my_login>:<my_pass>@<proxy_ip>:<proxy_port>/";
```

my Dockerfile:

```
from ubuntu:latest

COPY ./rss/apt.conf /apt.conf
ENV HTTP_PROXY=<ip>:<port>
ENV HTTPS_PROXY=<ip>:<port>

RUN apt update && apt install -y curl
RUN cat /apt.conf >> /etc/apt/apt.conf

ENTRYPOINT ["sleep","1000"]
```

Docker version:
`Docker version 20.10.8, build 3967b7d`

Comment: I assume you want to set the system-wide http proxy. The `Acquire::http::Proxy` in `apt.conf` does not do this. It merely sets the mirror that `apt` uses.

Comment: this is useful, thank you. Do you know a way to set proxy credentials for system-wide configuration?